# Replacing values of a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
d1 = {('a', 'b'): 300.0,
 ('b, 'c'): '0.1*K1',
 ('a', 'c'): 0.462,
 ('c', 'e'): '0.2*K2',
 ('b', 'a'): '0.1*K1',
 ('c','d'): 'K1*K3'}
K1, K2, K3 = 2.1, 3.4, 2
```

I want to replace `'0.1*K1'` in d1 with 0.1*K1 and `'0.2*K2'` in d2 with 0.2*K2, and so on. The values in `d1` that need to be replaced are given as keys in `d2`, and they are to be replaced with corresponding values in `d2`:

```
d2 = {'0.1*K1':0.1*K1, '0.1*K2':'0.1*K2', 'K2*K3':K2*K3}
```

The end result would be a dictionary:

```
d1_new = {('a', 'b'): 300.0,
     ('b, 'c'): 0.21,
     ('a', 'c'): 0.462,
     ('c', 'e'): 0.68,
     ('b', 'a'): 0.21',
     ('c','d'): 6.8}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried and then we can help

Comment: I tried converting it to a dataframe with keys of d1 in column labeled 'Rate', and then using df['Rate'].replace(d2). But it seems to take a lot of time when I have a big dataframe and I need to do multiple calculations.

Comment: If you're doing expression evaluation, consider [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dictionary comprehension with `get`:

```
d1_new = {k: d2.get(v, v) for k, v in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
{('a', 'b'): 300.0, ('b', 'c'): 0.21000000000000002, ('a', 'c'): 0.462, ('c', 'e'): 0.68, ('b', 'a'): 0.21000000000000002, ('c', 'd'): 4.2}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) to evaluate the expression:

```
d2 = {key: eval(str(value)) for key, value in d1.items()}
```

Which would result into:

```
{
    ('a', 'b'): 300.0,
    ('b', 'c'): 0.21000000000000002,
    ('a', 'c'): 0.462,
    ('c', 'e'): 0.68,
    ('b', 'a'): 0.21000000000000002,
    ('c', 'd'): 4.2
}
```

Comment: `eval` is not the savest

Comment: Just like anything else, `eval` is as safe as you make it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary comprehension:

```
d1_new = { k : d2[v] if v in d2 else v for (k, v) in d1.items() }
```

assuming you change `d2` to this:

```
d2 = {'0.1*K1':0.1*K1, '0.2*K2':0.2*K2, 'K1*K3':K1*K3}
```

so that they keys in `d2` do match what is in `d1`, then the output is as you desire:

```
{
    ('a', 'b'): 300.0,
    ('b', 'c'): 0.21000000000000002,
    ('a', 'c'): 0.462,
    ('c', 'e'): 0.68,
    ('b', 'a'): 0.21000000000000002,
    ('c', 'd'): 4.2
}
```